# EF Core query and projection to dto doesn't fill the property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, orm

How to write EF Core query to fill the properties in certain order?

```cs
public record PersonDto : BaseDto //Id is Guid
{
    public string Firstname { get; init; }
    public string Lastname { get; init; }

    public DateOnly Birthday { get; init; }

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Guid> AddressesIds { get; init; }

    public Guid? MainAddressId { get; init; }
}

internal class Person : SoftDeletableEntity //Id is Guid
{
    public Person()
    {
        Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
        Emails = new HashSet<Email>();
        PhoneNumbers = new HashSet<PhoneNumber>();
    }

    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public DateOnly Birthday { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public Guid? MainAddressId => MainAddress?.Id;

    public Address? MainAddress => Addresses.Where(adr => adr.IsPrimary).FirstOrDefault();
}

internal sealed partial class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Person> People => Set<Person>();
}

var context = new Context();
var peopleQuery = context.People
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(p=> new PersonDto(){
    AddressesIds = new HashSet<Guid>(p.Addresses.Select(a => a.Id).Where(a => a.IsPrimary),
    MainAddressId = p.MainAddressId,
    //bla bla 
};
var peopleResult = people.ToList();
```

At the end of this fragment, `peopleResult` has all the addresses ids have been loaded, but the `MainAddressId` of the dto is null.

When I debug the code, `MainAddressId` is called before populate the list of `Addresses`, how I change this, or how is this supposed to be done if I'm doing it wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not put business logic inside the entity. That should be put in the business logic layer. Query the data manually in your business logic layer when you put it in the dto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need **MainAddressId** and **MainAddress** properties of the **Person**. As I understand you have these in the **Address** model? You can just do the select like this:

```
var peopleQuery = context.People
    .Skip(10)
    .Take(10)
    .Select(p=> new PersonDto(){
    AddressesIds = new HashSet<Guid>(p.Addresses.Select(a=> a.Id),
    MainAddressId = p.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(a=> a.IsPrimary),
};
var peopleResult = people.ToList();
```

You need only the Addresses, then you can easily filter which is the main one, and assign it to the DTO's property.

Comment: I didn't think about it. I feel so dumb.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem is that calculated properties in your entity. I had a similar problem a few months ago. I just removed that properties from my Entity an put it in my DTOs.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).